# Export all environment properties from Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have set environment properties in AWS Elastic beanstalk. I have a nodejs application which is hosted on a linux.

I can read the environment properties by using container_commands in a config in ebextensions.

But is there another way to read those values? Can you export a json or something of all the values without reading them as environment variables in ebextensions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get environment variables with `get-command` on a Beanstalk EC2 instance:

```
sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output json
```

Comment: `--output json` no longer required - defaults to JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
commands:
    setvars:
        command: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "export \(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' > /etc/profile.d/sh.local
packages:
    yum:
        jq: []
```

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/